# Strongly type absolute navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using prism with Xamarin forms.

Is it possible to specify absolute navigation when using strongly typed navigation?

I know how to do it with uri navigation but would prefer to stay away from the magic strings.

**EDIT:**

This question was possibly poorly worded. I wanted to know if I could use absolute navigation (to reset the navigation stack) while using view model navigation. I have since confirmed it's not possible and neither is navigating to a page within a navigation page.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/673#issuecomment-229564694

I have since changed to using page navigation using a uri builder system like the accepted answer.

Comment: Have a look at FreshMvvm with ViewModel to ViewModel navigation. Another good option is MvvmCross.

Comment: An absolute URL by definition needs a magic string - since you application can be hosted under any domain.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have clarified that I mean specifically with using prism in Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said, an absolute URI is a string.

Defining constants like he explained may be your best bet.

For simple-page navigation (not doing multiple, just "Go here"), you can use nameof(ClassType) to get the URI version, or you could take nameof() a step furthur and make a provider that generates your magic strings based on an array of classtypes.

for example,

```
_navigation.Navigate(_navigation.CreateURI(nameof(HomePage), nameof(LoginPage), nameof(HelpPage)));
```

Where CreateURI is a extension method on NavigationService you make that takes in a list of params of type Page/ContentPage. This would ultimately keep you from using magic strings (keep it refactoring safe) without needing to make a separate constant for each instance.

It could look something like this (Tested and works):

```
public static class PrismExtensionMethods {
    public static string CreateURI(this INavigationService @this, params string[] pages) {
        var result = "";
        foreach(var item in pages) {
            result += item + "/";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I had wondered about doing that. As a follow up, do you how to use a navigation page with strongly typed navigation?

Comment: Sorry, when you say strongly typed, do you mean absolute navigation in comparison to relative navigation? If you mean absolute, _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://www.brianlagunas.com/MainPage", UriKind.Absolute); is how you would do that. If you mean something else that I am not understanding, please explain it. I'm having a brainfart on what strongly typed navigation would be.

Comment: Also, that absolute example I came up with was from this link, https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms/3-NavigationService.md

Comment: By strongly typed I mean the option to register a viewmodel along with your page such as `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();`

And then use that with `_navigationService.NavigateAsync<LoginPageViewModel>();`

And the original question was how to absolute navigation while maintaining that but now I'm wondering how you can use a navigation page with that.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute URI is a string. So your best option is to define a constant and use that.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the ToString of an enum as 'constants'. The enum contains all possible navigation options. Registering the page:

`_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>(UiExperience.Main.ToString());`

Navigating to the page:

`NavigationService.Navigate($"{UiExperience.Main}");`

or

```
NavigationService.Navigate($"{UiExperience.Main}/{UiExperience.DetailsNavigation}/{UiExperience.WorkOrderOverview}"
```

This is just like Jerry Nixon suggests [here](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/08/strongly-typed-experiences-in-prism.html).